Flutter `Listener` detect events outside the rendered child area
I have a special case where I have a Listener that detects onPointerHover events on a widget that can be transformed in many ways like rotate, scale, translate. I want now a user to be able to resize the widget when he moves the mouse to a corner of the widget which should detect between a range of -5px and +5px. To detect this inside is no problem, even if it's transformed, I can use localPosition and get the correct point back. The difficulty is listening outside doesn't work because it's outside the rendered widget area. Of course, I can set the listener to the top of the widget tree, but that will make it complicated to get the position where the user is hovering on my widget when it's transformed.
However, my current plan is to extend the current Listener with a custom solution that also emits when the user is outside of the rendered child. In my opinion, the problem is that it does not detect outside events within the Renderbox class.
 bool hitTest(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
    assert(() { /* Some code */  }());
    
    /// The following line may be the problem
    if (_size!.contains(position)) {
      if (hitTestChildren(result, position: position) || hitTestSelf(position)) {
        result.add(BoxHitTestEntry(this, position));
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

The problem is now even if I override the hitTest method nothing happens and in fact the print('hit'); is never printed to the console either. What am I doing wrong, or is there some other method that blocks the events?

class ExtendedRenderProxyBox extends RenderBox with RenderObjectWithChildMixin<RenderBox>, RenderProxyBoxMixin<RenderBox> {
  ExtendedRenderProxyBox([RenderBox? child]) {
    this.child = child;
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
    print('hit');
    return true;
  }
}


I found a solution by myself. I use the defer_pointer package and also create my own Listener widget like below.
OutsideListener
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

import 'outside_gesture_behavior.dart';
import 'outside_render_proxy_box.dart';

class OutsideListener extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  /// Creates a widget that forwards point events to callbacks.
  ///
  /// The [behavior] argument defaults to [HitTestBehavior.deferToChild].
  const OutsideListener({
    super.key,
    this.onPointerDown,
    this.onPointerMove,
    this.onPointerUp,
    this.onPointerHover,
    this.onPointerCancel,
    this.onPointerPanZoomStart,
    this.onPointerPanZoomUpdate,
    this.onPointerPanZoomEnd,
    this.onPointerSignal,
    this.behavior = OutsideHitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
    super.child,
  });

  /// Called when a pointer comes into contact with the screen (for touch
  /// pointers), or has its button pressed (for mouse pointers) at this widget's
  /// location.
  final PointerDownEventListener? onPointerDown;

  /// Called when a pointer that triggered an [onPointerDown] changes position.
  final PointerMoveEventListener? onPointerMove;

  /// Called when a pointer that triggered an [onPointerDown] is no longer in
  /// contact with the screen.
  final PointerUpEventListener? onPointerUp;

  /// Called when a pointer that has not triggered an [onPointerDown] changes
  /// position.
  ///
  /// This is only fired for pointers which report their location when not down
  /// (e.g. mouse pointers, but not most touch pointers).
  final PointerHoverEventListener? onPointerHover;

  /// Called when the input from a pointer that triggered an [onPointerDown] is
  /// no longer directed towards this receiver.
  final PointerCancelEventListener? onPointerCancel;

  /// Called when a pan/zoom begins such as from a trackpad gesture.
  final PointerPanZoomStartEventListener? onPointerPanZoomStart;

  /// Called when a pan/zoom is updated.
  final PointerPanZoomUpdateEventListener? onPointerPanZoomUpdate;

  /// Called when a pan/zoom finishes.
  final PointerPanZoomEndEventListener? onPointerPanZoomEnd;

  /// Called when a pointer signal occurs over this object.
  ///
  /// See also:
  ///
  ///  * [PointerSignalEvent], which goes into more detail on pointer signal
  ///    events.
  final PointerSignalEventListener? onPointerSignal;

  /// How to behave during hit testing.
  final OutsideHitTestBehavior behavior;

  @override
  OutsideRenderPointerListener createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return OutsideRenderPointerListener(
      onPointerDown: onPointerDown,
      onPointerMove: onPointerMove,
      onPointerUp: onPointerUp,
      onPointerHover: onPointerHover,
      onPointerCancel: onPointerCancel,
      onPointerPanZoomStart: onPointerPanZoomStart,
      onPointerPanZoomUpdate: onPointerPanZoomUpdate,
      onPointerPanZoomEnd: onPointerPanZoomEnd,
      onPointerSignal: onPointerSignal,
      behavior: behavior,
    );
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(BuildContext context, OutsideRenderPointerListener renderObject) {
    renderObject
      ..onPointerDown = onPointerDown
      ..onPointerMove = onPointerMove
      ..onPointerUp = onPointerUp
      ..onPointerHover = onPointerHover
      ..onPointerCancel = onPointerCancel
      ..onPointerPanZoomStart = onPointerPanZoomStart
      ..onPointerPanZoomUpdate = onPointerPanZoomUpdate
      ..onPointerPanZoomEnd = onPointerPanZoomEnd
      ..onPointerSignal = onPointerSignal
      ..behavior = behavior;
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    final List<String> listeners = <String>[
      if (onPointerDown != null) 'down',
      if (onPointerMove != null) 'move',
      if (onPointerUp != null) 'up',
      if (onPointerHover != null) 'hover',
      if (onPointerCancel != null) 'cancel',
      if (onPointerPanZoomStart != null) 'panZoomStart',
      if (onPointerPanZoomUpdate != null) 'panZoomUpdate',
      if (onPointerPanZoomEnd != null) 'panZoomEnd',
      if (onPointerSignal != null) 'signal',
    ];
    properties.add(IterableProperty<String>('listeners', listeners, ifEmpty: '<none>'));
    properties.add(EnumProperty<OutsideHitTestBehavior>('behavior', behavior));
  }
}

class OutsideRenderPointerListener extends OutsideRenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior {
  /// Creates a render object that forwards pointer events to callbacks.
  ///
  /// The [behavior] argument defaults to [OutsideHitTestBehavior.deferToChild].
  OutsideRenderPointerListener({
    this.onPointerDown,
    this.onPointerMove,
    this.onPointerUp,
    this.onPointerHover,
    this.onPointerCancel,
    this.onPointerPanZoomStart,
    this.onPointerPanZoomUpdate,
    this.onPointerPanZoomEnd,
    this.onPointerSignal,
    super.behavior,
    super.child,
  });

  /// Called when a pointer comes into contact with the screen (for touch
  /// pointers), or has its button pressed (for mouse pointers) at this widget's
  /// location.
  PointerDownEventListener? onPointerDown;

  /// Called when a pointer that triggered an [onPointerDown] changes position.
  PointerMoveEventListener? onPointerMove;

  /// Called when a pointer that triggered an [onPointerDown] is no longer in
  /// contact with the screen.
  PointerUpEventListener? onPointerUp;

  /// Called when a pointer that has not an [onPointerDown] changes position.
  PointerHoverEventListener? onPointerHover;

  /// Called when the input from a pointer that triggered an [onPointerDown] is
  /// no longer directed towards this receiver.
  PointerCancelEventListener? onPointerCancel;

  /// Called when a pan/zoom begins such as from a trackpad gesture.
  PointerPanZoomStartEventListener? onPointerPanZoomStart;

  /// Called when a pan/zoom is updated.
  PointerPanZoomUpdateEventListener? onPointerPanZoomUpdate;

  /// Called when a pan/zoom finishes.
  PointerPanZoomEndEventListener? onPointerPanZoomEnd;

  /// Called when a pointer signal occurs over this object.
  PointerSignalEventListener? onPointerSignal;

  @override
  Size computeSizeForNoChild(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return constraints.biggest;
  }

  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event, HitTestEntry entry) {
    assert(debugHandleEvent(event, entry));
    if (event is PointerDownEvent) {
      return onPointerDown?.call(event);
    }
    if (event is PointerMoveEvent) {
      return onPointerMove?.call(event);
    }
    if (event is PointerUpEvent) {
      return onPointerUp?.call(event);
    }
    if (event is PointerHoverEvent) {
      return onPointerHover?.call(event);
    }
    if (event is PointerCancelEvent) {
      return onPointerCancel?.call(event);
    }
    if (event is PointerPanZoomStartEvent) {
      return onPointerPanZoomStart?.call(event);
    }
    if (event is PointerPanZoomUpdateEvent) {
      return onPointerPanZoomUpdate?.call(event);
    }
    if (event is PointerPanZoomEndEvent) {
      return onPointerPanZoomEnd?.call(event);
    }
    if (event is PointerSignalEvent) {
      return onPointerSignal?.call(event);
    }
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(FlagsSummary<Function?>(
      'listeners',
      <String, Function?>{
        'down': onPointerDown,
        'move': onPointerMove,
        'up': onPointerUp,
        'hover': onPointerHover,
        'cancel': onPointerCancel,
        'panZoomStart': onPointerPanZoomStart,
        'panZoomUpdate': onPointerPanZoomUpdate,
        'panZoomEnd': onPointerPanZoomEnd,
        'signal': onPointerSignal,
      },
      ifEmpty: '<none>',
    ));
  }
}


OutsideHitTestBehavior
/// How to behave during hit tests.
enum OutsideHitTestBehavior {
  /// Targets that defer to their children receive events within their bounds
  /// only if one of their children is hit by the hit test.
  deferToChild,

  /// Opaque targets can be hit by hit tests, causing them to both receive
  /// events within their bounds and prevent targets visually behind them from
  /// also receiving events.
  opaque,

  /// Translucent targets both receive events within their bounds and permit
  /// targets visually behind them to also receive events.
  translucent,

  /// Targets all events even if they are outside the widget.
  all,
}

OutsideRenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

import 'outside_gesture_behavior.dart';

abstract class OutsideRenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior extends RenderProxyBox {
  /// Initializes member variables for subclasses.
  ///
  /// By default, the [behavior] is [OutsideHitTestBehavior.deferToChild].
  OutsideRenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior({
    this.behavior = OutsideHitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
    RenderBox? child,
  }) : super(child);

  /// How to behave during hit testing when deciding how the hit test propagates
  /// to children and whether to consider targets behind this one.
  ///
  /// Defaults to [OutsideHitTestBehavior.deferToChild].
  ///
  /// See [OutsideHitTestBehavior] for the allowed values and their meanings.
  OutsideHitTestBehavior behavior;

  @override
  bool hitTest(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
    bool hitTarget = false;

    if (behavior == OutsideHitTestBehavior.all) {
      result.add(BoxHitTestEntry(this, position));
    }

    if (size.contains(position)) {
      hitTarget = hitTestChildren(result, position: position) || hitTestSelf(position);
      if (behavior != OutsideHitTestBehavior.all) {
        if (hitTarget || behavior == OutsideHitTestBehavior.translucent) {
          result.add(BoxHitTestEntry(this, position));
        }
      }
    }
    return hitTarget;
  }

  @override
  bool hitTestSelf(Offset position) => behavior == OutsideHitTestBehavior.opaque;

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(EnumProperty<OutsideHitTestBehavior>('behavior', behavior, defaultValue: null));
  }
}

